# How to assign callbacks to Materialize Modal

Tags: modal-dialog, aurelia, materialize

Materialize modals have four callbacks, onOpenStart, onOpenEnd, onCloseStart, onCloseEnd.
I am unable to find a way to assign these, since there does not appear to be any of:
modalinstance.onOpenStart=function;
or
modalinstance.options.onOpenStart=function;

So where can you set these callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the four callbacks in the `options` parameter of `M.Modal.init`:

```
var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
```

Here the options argument is a object with the callback functions:

```
var options = {
    onOpenStart: function(modal, trigger) {
        // code
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I was actually using a beta version that did not have this feature, put in by an earlier programmer. Upgraded to version 1 andthere it was. Duh, and apologies.